# spring-jpa how to get EntityNotFoundException or similar on find* query methods?

Tags: java, exception, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm struggling with following problem: 
I don't want to get Null reference if there's no object in database.

Answer (score 1):

All the JPA providers I have tried will return an empty list if there are no matches to the query.

Also,

```
CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(resultList);
```

Is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Is it allowed -in your project to use `getReference()` method? If yes, then please use it to avoid null reference being returned.

`getReference(Class<T>,Object)` throws an `EntityNotFoundException` if it cant find the entity being searched for.

Or else, if you has to use find() method, then you may handle `null` manually i.e. with the help of `if..else` block. etc.